# Pass Guid parameter to web api controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I try to pass guid as parameter to my web api controller. Client side:

```
$http.post("/api/someapi/remove",{id:someId});
```

Web api action signature:

```
public MyType Remove(Guid id){}
```

Parameter `someId` is a string representation of a valid Guid. But when I try to send data I always get `404` error. I read a lot of topics about that but didn`t find any that helps me

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `[FromBody]` in the method parameter.

Please replace it with below

```
public MyType Remove([FromBody]Guid id){}
```